# Set TMPDIR globally in Ansible to use Docker with noexec flag on /tmp

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, environment-variables, tmp

For security reasons, we have `/tmp` mounted with noexec-flag. Since docker need the exec-flag, running any docker-compose command like `docker-compose --version` would result in the following error:

```
docker-compose: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

This could be fixed on the CLI [by setting the `TMPDIR` env variable to a local path like the home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068483/9428314). But in Ansible this doesn't work, since it's not spawning a login shell. We got an Ansible playbook with a lot of `docker-compose` cli calls and they ignore `TMPDIR` exported in e.g. `/etc/environment`.

It only works when specifying `TMPDIR` as environment variable with an absolute path like this:

```
- name: Check if all applications are is running
  shell: |
    docker-compose ps | grep Up | wc -l
  changed_when: running.stdout != item.services_num
  register: running
  with_items:
    - "{{ docker_applications }}"
  environment:
    TMPDIR: /home/myuser
```

Since this results in many code changes and overhead, I'm searching how to set this globally. [`remote_tmp`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/55925#issuecomment-487972274) should be able to fix this, so I set it in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
remote_tmp = /home/myuser
```

This doesn't work and I can't find the directive in the Ansible 2.9, 2.8 or 2.9 [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/reference_appendices/config.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278701/3276634) that allows to specifiy the env variable using an ansible variable at playbook level like this:

```
- name: Setting custom TMPDIR for docker
  hosts: all
  environment: 
    TMPDIR: "{{ tmp_dir }}"
  vars:
    tmp_dir: /home/myuser
    # Verify that it works by making a negative test with the wrong temp dir that results in libz.so.1 segment failed error
    #tmp_dir: /tmp
  tasks:
    - name: Test tmpdir
      shell: "echo $TMPDIR; docker-compose --version
```

It's important to specify an absolute path. `tmp_dir: ~` doesn't work. Even better would be fetching the home directory from Ansibles variables:

```
- name: Setting custom TMPDIR for docker
  hosts: all
  environment: 
    TMPDIR: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Test tmpdir
      shell: "echo $TMPDIR; docker-compose --version"
```

This avoids manually maintaining system-specific paths at all, so it could be easily re-used.

It's still not a perfect solution, but at least we can set this just for the main playbook instead of having tons of `environment` directives for each task.