# Persist environment variables for future ansible tasks

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible

i´m triying to set in my localhost via a play env vars for future tasks/playbooks in the same localhost.

```
- name: Environment_vars
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    env_vars: /opt/env_vars.yml
    env_path: ~/.bashrc
  tasks:

  - name: put into .bashrc
    lineinfile:
        path: "{{env_path}}"
        state: present
        regexp: "^{{ item.key }}="
        line: "export {{item.key}}={{item.value}}"
    with_dict: "{{ env_vars_dict }}"
    become: yes

  - name: test bash
    shell: source ~/.bashrc
```

i have tried all of this methods that i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733511/how-to-set-linux-environment-variables-with-ansible), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775099/how-to-set-environmental-variables-using-ansible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278092/ansible-playbook-environment-variables). All of them worked but only inside the tasks. Including also, tasks to restart or source the shell, however didn´t work.

Is there any chance to set env vars in a play and use in the next play via 'ansible.builtin.env lookup'? and also these new vars stay in the 'env'??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Environment variables are process-local on UNIX (Windows has a persistence mechanism through the registry, but UNIX ain't Windows). They're not _supposed_ to last past the current process and its children, and in general, I advise against designing things that lead you to need them to be persisted.

Comment: That said, it would do this question a lot of good if you added a [mre] that shows how you're testing for success and otherwise provides everything someone needs to see the problem themselves -- that way we could be sure that I'm interpreting your question correctly above.

Comment: Please explain what information you're trying to retain and why you're trying to do so in an environment variable. This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Set env vars in a play and use in the next play."***

A: It is not possible. You can set [*environment*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) in the scope of a play. There is no such thing as a 'scope of a playbook'. For example, the second play knows nothing about the environment set in the first play only

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    MY_VAR1: my variable 1
  tasks:
    - command: echo $MY_VAR1
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: echo $MY_VAR1
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  out.stdout: my variable 1
  out.stdout: $MY_VAR1
```

As a workaround, you can put the environment into the *vars*. For example, into the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/my_env.yml 
my_env:
  MY_VAR1: my variable 1
  MY_VAR2: my variable 2
```

Then, you can use it  in each play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  environment: "{{ my_env }}"
  tasks:
    - command: echo $MY_VAR1
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

- hosts: localhost
  environment: "{{ my_env }}"
  tasks:
    - command: echo $MY_VAR1
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  out.stdout: my variable 1
  out.stdout: my variable 1
```

---

Q: ***"Set env vars in a play and use ansible.builtin.env"***

A: The lookup plugin *env* never returns environment set via the keyword *environment*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    MY_VAR1: my variable 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'SHELL') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'MY_VAR1') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: /bin/bash
  msg: ''
```

Any lookup plugin is always running on the localhost. The plugin *env* returns the environment inherited from the shell running the ansible-* utility.

Both *command* and *shell* modules do not run the commands in the inherited environment. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    MY_VAR1: my variable 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'MY_VAR3') }}"
    - command: echo $MY_VAR3 $MY_VAR1
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> MY_VAR3='my variable 3' ansible-playbook pb.yml

  msg: my variable 3
  out.stdout: $MY_VAR3 my variable 1
```

Comment: Thanks! this explains a lots. Is only apply to playbooks in localhost or for playbooks in other hosts too?

Comment: The *environment* will apply to all hosts in the play, of course. Test it.